# Search and replace with "whole word only" option

Tags: python

I have a script that runs into my text and search and replace all the sentences I write based in a database.

The script:

```
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editor.replace(s[0],s[1])
```

And the Database example:

```
Event*Evento*
result*resultado*
```

And so on...

Now what is happening is that I need the "whole word only" in that script, because I'm finding myself with problems.

For example with `Result` and `Event`, because when I replace for `Resultado` and `Evento`, and I run the script one more time in the text the script replace again the `Resultado` and `Evento`.

And the result after I run the script stays like this `Resultadoado` and `Eventoo`.

Just so you guys know.. Its not only for Event and Result, there is more then 1000+ sentences that I already set for the search and replace to work..

I don't need a simples search and replace for two words.. because I'm going to be editing the database over and over for different sentences..

Comment: is `editor` a string?

Answer (score 30):

You want a regular expression. You can use the token `\b` to match a word boundary: i.e., `\bresult\b` would match only the exact word "result."

```
import re

with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editor = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % s[0] , s[1], editor)
```

Comment: i should replace that in for my currently script? and in the database i should add the \b before each word ?

Comment: for example \bresult*\bresultado* ?

Comment: Just replace the code you have with this... the script adds the `\b`s so you don't have to have them in the "database".

Comment: so i replace the code you wrote for the one that was in my script.. then i save.. then i wrote "Result" in a 3rd tab and add the Result*Resultado* into my database.. then i ran the script .. but it didnt work out

Comment: @RenanCidale:  Add `\b` before and after each word you want to match, but not at all to the replacement string.  Make sure that you us raw strings (`r'a raw string'`) otherwise `'\b'` is interpreted as a backspace.

Comment: @kindall:  Perhaps change `s[0]` to `re.escape(s[0])` just in case the source data contains characters that can be interpreted as regular expressions.  But it could be overkill.

Comment: im feeling so stupid right now.. i can understand anything that you guys are trying to say..

Comment: import re

with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Portuguesetranslator.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = l.split('*')
        editor = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % s[0] , s[1], editor)  i replace that code you said by my script.. then i tried to run the script into my text .. and it didnt work out

Comment: Please dont give up on me !

Comment: @RenanCidale did you managed to get a solution for your dictionary problem?

Answer (score 20):

Use `re.sub`:

```
replacements = {'the':'a', 
                'this':'that'}

def replace(match):
    return replacements[match.group(0)]

# notice that the 'this' in 'thistle' is not matched 
print re.sub('|'.join(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s) for s in replacements), 
        replace, 'the cat has this thistle.')
```

Prints

```
a cat has that thistle.
```

*Notes:*

- All the strings to be replaced are joined into a single pattern so
  that the string needs to be looped over just once.
- The source strings are passed to `re.escape` to make avoid
  interpreting them as regular expressions.
- The words are surrounded by `r'\b'` to make sure matches are for
  whole words only.
- A replacement function is used so that any match can be replaced.

Answer (score 14):

Use `re.sub` instead of normal string replace to replace only whole words.So your script,even if it runs again will not replace the already replaced words.

```
>>> import re
>>> editor = "This is result of the match"
>>> new_editor = re.sub(r"\bresult\b","resultado",editor)
>>> new_editor
'This is resultado of the match'
>>> newest_editor = re.sub(r"\bresult\b","resultado",new_editor)
>>> newest_editor
'This is resultado of the match'
```

Comment: where do i replace that

Comment: just so you know.. the database contains more then 1400 words .. and Result and Event are just examples..

Comment: To introduce a variable in replacement use: `re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(variable),"resultado",editor)` where `variable = "result"`.

Comment: this is cool for me

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple. use re.sub, don't use replace.

```
import re
replacements = {r'\bthe\b':'a', 
                r'\bthis\b':'that'}

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = re.sub(i,j,text)
    return text

replace_all("the cat has this thistle.", replacements)
```

It will print

```
a cat has that thistle.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

match = {}  # create a dictionary of words-to-replace and words-to-replace-with

f = open("filename", "r")
data = f.read()  # string of all file content


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % i, j, text)
        # r"\b%s\b"% enables replacing by whole word matches only
    return text


data = replace_all(data, match)
print(data)  # you can copy and paste the result to whatever file you like
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It still replaces partial matches. Please check