# Replace exact match word with specific string in python

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python and this is my first script to replace word.

my file `test.c` contains following two lines

```
printf("\nReboot not supported.  Exiting instead.\n");
fprintf(stderr, "FATAL:  operation not supported!\n");
```

Now I want to replace `printf` and `fprintf` by `//printf` and `//fprintf` respectively.

Here is what I have tried

```
infile = open('path\to\input\test.c')
outfile = open('path\to\output\test.c', 'w')

replacements = {'printf':'//printf', 'fprintf':'//fprintf'}

for line in infile:
    for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(src, target)
    outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

But using this I got

`fprintf` to `//f//printf` which is wrong.

For the solution have looked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730788/search-and-replace-with-python-script-with-whole-word-only-option) but not able to fit it in my script.

Anyone have idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to convert printf to //printf and fprintf to //fprintf. If that's the case then this might work, try it out.

```
  outfile = open("test.c", 'r')
  temp = outfile.read()
  temp = re.sub("printf", "//printf", temp)
  temp = re.sub("f//printf", "//fprintf", temp)
  outfile.close()
  outfile = open("test.c","w")
  outfile.write(temp)
  outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

dict in python is not ordered. so you cannot guarantee `print` or `fprintf` will be picked up first while traversing dict in the following line:

```
for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
```

In the current case, `print` looks to be picked first thats why you are facing the issue. In order to avoid the issue, either use [orderdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or keep list of dicts for `replacements`.

Comment: How can use `Orderdict`? Have tried by `OrderedDict(sorted(replacements.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))` but getting error for undefined `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what it's doing. The dictionaries are not ordered (as you may think they are) so the `fprintf` replacement actually comes first and then it replaces the `printf` portion of it. Sequence:

```
fprintf -> //fprintf -> //f//printf
```

Comment: So how can i avoid this?

Comment: Using orderdict as mentioned above will allow you to utilize a dictionary that adheres to the key ordering it was entered with, or you can use a list instead. Should solve the issue.

Comment: @Jayesh to avoid that, you can you list or, tuple instead of dict `[('printf','//printf'), ('fprintf','//fprintf')]`

Comment: @dragon2fly Tried by `replacements = [{'printf':'//printf', 'fprintf':'//fprintf'}]` but got error like `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`.

Comment: Careful with your brackets. Curly brackets indicate a dictionary... You want the rounded ones.

Comment: @Jayesh you still use dict inside a list, that cause error. `replacements =[('printf','//printf'), ('fprintf','//fprintf')]` will work fine

Comment: @KyleBooth Tried with round one but again error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @dragon2fly Have tried like `replacements = [('printf','//printf'), ('fprintf','//fprintf')]`  but again error like `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: @Jayesh you dont need `replacements.iteritems()`, just `replacements` is enough.

Comment: @dragon2fly Error gone but now `fprintf` become `f//printf`.

Comment: @Jayesh you need to put the `fprintf` replacement as the first tuple in the list like so: `[ ('fprintf','//fprintf'), ('printf','//printf')]`

Comment: @KyleBooth No. not working..it become `fprintf` to `//f//printf` and this is in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=\bprintf\b|\bfprintf\b)
```

Use `re.sub` from re module.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/18

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?=\bprintf\b|\bfprintf\b)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "printf(\"\nReboot not supported. Exiting instead.\n\");\nfprintf(stderr, \"FATAL: operation not supported!\n\");"
subst = "//"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Pass your file line by line and print output to different file.