# almost similar keys in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which contains the below column:

```
column_name
CUVITRU 8 gram
CUVITRU 1 grams
```

I want to replace these gram and grams to gm. So I have created a dictionary

```
dict_ = {'gram':'gm','grams':'gm'}
```

I am able to replace it but it is converting grams to gms. Below is the column after conversion:

```
column_name
CUVITRU 8 gm
CUVITRU 1 gms
```

How can I solve this issue.

Below is my code:

```
dict_ = {'gram':'gm','grams':'gm'}
for key, value in dict_abbr.items():
    my_string = my_string.replace(key,value)

my_string = ' '.join(unique_list(my_string.split()))
def unique_list(l):
    ulist = []
    [ulist.append(x) for x in l if x not in ulist]
    return ulist
```

Comment: Are these in a pandas dataframe?  Could you provide some code to generate an object similar to the ones you're working with?

Comment: It's because `'gram':'gm'` is listed first in your dictionary. So it replaces the "gram" within "grams" and the result is "gms". If you put `'gram':'gm'` after `'grams':'gm'` it should work fine

Comment: Yes it is an pandas dataframe

Comment: @Reedinationer I have tried that.. it's still the same

Comment: You don't really care about the dict, just the key/value pairs returned by its `items()` method. Just store a list of tuples in the first place (in the desired order): `d = [("grams", "gm"), ("gram", "gm")]`.

Comment: @Reedinationer dict keys are hashed, changing order in definition does not change iteration results

Comment: @danchik It does as of Python 3.7, where a dict is guaranteed to retain the insertion order of its keys.

Answer (score 1):

because it finds 'gram' in 'grams', one way is to instead of string use reg exp for replacement on word boundaries, like `(r"\b%s\....`  look at the answer usign .sub here for example: [search-and-replace-with-whole-word-only-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730788/search-and-replace-with-whole-word-only-option)

Answer (score 0):

Put the longer string `grams` before the shorter one `gram` like this `{'grams':'gm','gram':'gm'}`, and it will work.
Well, I’m using a recent python 3 like 3.7.2 which guarantees that the sequence of retrieving items is the same as that they are created in the dictionary. For earlier Pythons that may happen (and this appears to be the problem) but isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: keys in dict are not ordered, but hashed, it will not work because the changing order of keys in dict will not change order they are returned in for loop

Comment: But that is why OP has this problem - the gram replace happens first.

Comment: Then you probably aren't using Python 3.7.

Comment: See some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: No I am using Python 3.7 only

Comment: @barny You have the wrong type of quotes in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually care about the dict; you care about the key/value pairs produced by its `items()` method, so just store that in the first place. This lets you specify the order of replacements to try regardless of your Python version.

```
d = [('grams':'gm'), ('gram':'gm')]
for key, value in d:
    my_string = my_string.replace(key,value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make replacements in the reverse order of the key lengths instead:

```
dict_ = {'gram':'gm','grams':'gm'}
for key in sorted(dict_abbr, key=len, reverse=True):
    my_string = my_string.replace(key, dict_[key])
```