# No error when x.replace("y", " ") but "y" still in the list

Tags: python

I want to remove all stopwrods, stored in a list, from another list. Yet, though the programme doesn't give me any error, all the values are still in the list.

I did google and search for the solution of my problem, but the lack of error doesn't help.

```
#defined list of stopwords
stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", "of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"]
```

```
sentences = []
labels = []
with open(path_bbc, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        labels.append(row[0])
        sentence = row[1]
        for ele in stopwords: 
            sentence=sentence.replace("ele", " ")
            sentences.append(sentence)
  
print(len(sentences))
print(sentences[0])

#Expected output
# 2225
# tv future hands viewers home theatre systems plasma high-definition tvs digital video recorders moving living room way people watch tv will radically different five years time....
```

My output

```
340425
tv future in the hands of viewers with home theatre systems  plasma high-definition tvs  and digital video recorders moving into the living room  the way people watch tv will be radically different in five years  time.
```

As you can see all the stopwords like "in", "the" are still there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're replacing `"ele"`, not the loop variable `ele`.

Comment: Oh, that's right!!! I'm so sorry for being stupid! I removed citation marks, but the problem is that it also replaces single characters from words in the text. Have you got an idea why and how to fix that?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730788/search-and-replace-with-whole-word-only-option

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!